# Problemas con el metodo start y update en C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity, visual-studio-2019

**por mas que aplico las soluciones que me da visual studio 2019 me sigue saliendo ese mensaje, alguna solucion para este problema nose si es comun o si pero no encontre respuesta en ninguna paguina**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform playerTransform;
    public Vector3 cameraOffset = new Vector3(0, 3, 5);
    public float yPosition = 0;

    public float yaw = 180f;
    public float pitch = 20f;

    void Start()
    {
        playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = playerTransform.position + cameraOffset;
        transform.rotation = new Quaternion(
            transform.rotation.x,
            transform.rotation.y - yPosition,
            transform.rotation.z, transform.rotation.w);

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

[image: es el error que sale y le puse public para que tenga los accesos pero aun asi sigue apareciendo el error]

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente esta bien el código, pero si al ejecutarlo no funcionan las voids Start() y Update(), prueba lo siguiente, el mensaje que te muestra visual studio se refiere como miembro privado a este objeto:

```
private Transform playerTransform;
```

por lo tanto, remplaza esta liena por esta otra:

```
public Transform playerTransform = null;
```

Espero que esto te ayude!

Comment: eso haría que el transform fuera público en ese script. No es que sea malo, pero en el interfaz podrías asignarle el de otro objeto. Tampoco es que sea malo pero es muy probable que no interese tenerlo publico